On pages 164 and 165 in Jech's Set Theory
I am quite lost regarding a couple of paragraphs (picture at the end) in pages 161 and 162 of Jech's Set Theory. In particular:

Why is the LHS of $(12.16)$ not defined for all $\varphi\in Form$? Certainly definition 12.6 applies to all formulas in the language, right?

It seems to me that the definition of the RHS of $(12.16)$ is precisely the LHS, yielding the triviality $A\longleftrightarrow A$. Yet Jech states $(12.16)$ is "easily verified", which seems to imply there is something to be shown, and that thus my understanding is wrong somewhere.





$\varphi$ is different from $\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner$. The former is a formula, while the latter is just a set that belongs to another set that we decided to call $Form$. Definition 12.6, namely relativization, is defined by recursion in the metatheory. On the other hand, for a set $M$ the relation $(M,E)\models\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner[a_1,\dots,a_n]$ is defined by recursion on a suitable well-founded relation, like how you define exponentiation of natural numbers as repeated multiplication.

@newaccount Wait, if $\varphi$ is a formula, then is it not a logical notion? How would 12.6 be a definition in the _meta_theory? Certainly $\varphi^{M,E}$ is a formula in the language, right?

@newaccount also, how is $\lceil\varphi\rceil$ a set?

Please don't use images for mathematical texts.

I recommend you check out The Foundations of Mathematics by Kunen, especially III.2 on "formalizing things twice"
